# Enviar un objeto tipo Formdata a Php MVC

Tags: php, ajax, mvc, formdata

Estoy tratando de enviar la información de un formulario mediante un objeto de tipo FormData a un controlador en php. EN el controlador hago una impresion de lo que viene en el $_POST. Siempre que verifico en la consola, la respuesta me arroja un error. REviso el NETWORK y me muestra un status 200 indicando de que la peticion es exitosa, pero no puedo obtner los datos que deseo obtener.Agradezco cualquier Guía.

```
    PEtición ajax
    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#players_form').on('submit', players_form);
        function players_form(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let data = new FormData($('#players_form').get(0));
            //console.log(valueIdCategories.value,valueGenderId.value, valueIdGuardian.value);
            
            //Ajax Request
            $.ajax({
                url: 'playerController/create',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType :'json',
                processData: false,
                contentType:false,
                data,
                success:function(response){
                    console.log(response)
                },
                error:function(error){
                    console.log(error)
             }
                
            })
        }
    })
    
    
    Controlador donde envío la petición
    
    <?php
    
    require_once ("models/playerModel.php");
    
       
    
    class PlayerController extends PlayerModel
    {
    
        public function create()
        {
            print_r($_POST);
      require_once("views/userNew.php");
    
        }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, por favor edita la pregunta para poner el código como texto, porque es difícil analizarlo en una imagen. Aprovecha para leer primero [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y haz el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que sepas cómo funciona la plataforma y puedas obtener una respuesta apropiada.

Comment: @Triby Gracias por la recomendación.